# SSH host key check fails on Debian version, but not on MacOS version

Tags: ssh, known-hosts

I have this strange situation with host-key checking. `ssh -v github.com`:

- works with "OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3" on MacOS Mojave (10.14.5 (18F132)):

  ```
  debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa 
  SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
  debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in /Users/dominik/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  ```

  I then get asked for the passphrase.
- does *not* work with "OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019" on Docker image `debian:buster-20190708`:

  ```
  debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
  The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.118.4)' can't be established.
  RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
  Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
  ```

My `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file:

```
github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
```

The Docker command I used is:
`docker run --rm -it -v ~/.ssh/:/root/.ssh/ debian:buster-20190708 sh -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssh && ssh -v github.com'`

Comment: I don't see a problem? Just run the command: `ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` on your debian machine.

Comment: @notStan I want to use the `known_host` from my host machine as I've already checked that host's fingerprint. That's why I've included it in the Docker container `-v ~/.ssh/:/root/.ssh/`. Does that work for you?

Comment: @notStan Thanks for your hint. I've found the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer:

Run `ssh-keyscan -H`, as [@notStan mentioned in his comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/977780/ssh-host-key-check-fails-on-debian-version-but-not-on-macos-version?noredirect=1#comment1272248_977780), on the host machine. It hashes all hostnames in `known_hosts` (the original is backed up in `known_hosts.old`).

Debian's default OpenSSH config in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` sets the option [`HashKnownHosts yes`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#HashKnownHosts). It then seems to not read unhashed hostnames, in this case `github.com`.